# Rate of adaptive feasible mutation using GA

Tags: matlab, random, genetic-algorithm, mutation

I am optimizing a problem in MATLAB with GA (genetic algorithm). My problem involves constraints, and thus MATLAB uses the default mutation operator named  Adaptive Feasible. When reading about this in [the source](https://se.mathworks.com/help/gads/genetic-algorithm-options.html#f6633), I could not find information about the probability or rate of this operator.

What is the rate of this operator?